# Is multivariate probit the right approach?

Tags: econometrics, probit, multivariate-regression

I am interested in what determinants may drive a car manufacturing firm to sell its products only in specific countries. The same car can be available for sale in countries A and B but not in country C, and these choices from firm might be strongly correlated. That's why I'm thinking of a multivariate probit as one possible approach.

The choice to sell a car on a specific market A, B or C might depend on the car itself (the mass of the vehicle as a proxy of the type), on the firm characteristics (the size of the firm as measured by the total number of sales) and on the market itself (the total number of cars/drivers in country A, B or C).

My problem is I'm not sure if multivariate probit is the right approach if I want to add a country-level variable, such as the number of cars in the country for example, as it appears as just one scalar for each probit equation.

Can anyone confirm multivariate probit actually works to regress simultaneously the 3 binary choices (sell or not in countries A, B and C) given the 3 independent variables I mentioned? Otherwise, would you have further suggestions as what modelling framework could suit and, potentially how would it translate in an econometric software (R, Stata, Eviews)?

Additional question. As manufacturers produce different cars, how can I add firm effects for different cars from the same manufacturer?

Thanks for the help,
D.